# Django form with model choice filed

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a problem with form in django. I was create a model form but he not save choicefield to database.Form save only a title(CharField).I was create a function that solving problem but i think its bad and can be write much better. Any help?

**models.py**

```
TOPIC_CAT = [
   ('WEL', 'Spawlnictwo'),
   ('DIY', 'Majsterkowanie'),
   ('ELE', 'Elektryka'),
   ('IT', 'Informatyka'),
   ('CAT', 'Stolarstwo'),
]

class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TOPIC_CAT)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewTopic(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text', 'categories']
        labels = {'text':'Nazwa tematu', 'categories': 'Kategoria'}
```

**views.py**

```
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method!='POST':
       form = NewTopic()
    else:
       form = NewTopic(data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
          new_topic.categories = request.POST.get('categories')
          new_topic.save()
          return redirect('forum:topics_in_category', category=new_topic.categories)
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'forum/new_topic.html', context)
```

Second problem is a search form. I want the search field to be visible all the time like in stackoverflow website but i dont have idea how.Already did a button that open a new website with form.

Comment: Why do you use a different form for handling the POST? If it's intentional, can you add the `Search` form to the question

Comment: I did a mistake writing. Checking coda and i have NewTopic form.
Django throw my a error ,NewTopic has no attribute categories thats why i write this function